# How to send Map to Kafka topic so that ProducerRecord key is same as corresponding Map key

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I am using Spark streaming and data is being sent to Kafka. I am sending a Map to Kafka. Assuming I have a Map of 20(which may grow to 1000 in a Streaming Batch duration) elements like below:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> input = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        input.put(11,"One");
        input.put(312,"two");
        input.put(33,"One");
        input.put(24,"One");
        input.put(35,"One");
        input.put(612,"One");
        input.put(7,"One");
        input.put(128,"One");
        input.put(9,"One");
        input.put(10,"One");
        input.put(11,"One1");
        input.put(12,"two1");
        input.put(13,"One1");
        input.put(14,"One1");
        input.put(15,"One1");
        input.put(136,"One1");
        input.put(137,"One1");
        input.put(158,"One1");
        input.put(159,"One1");
        input.put(120,"One1");



        Set<Integer> inputKeys = input.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> inputKeysIterator = inputKeys.iterator();
        while (inputKeysIterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer key = inputKeysIterator.next();
            ProducerRecord<Integer, String> record = new ProducerRecord<Integer, String>(topic,
                    key%10, input.get(key));
            KafkaProducer.send(record);
        }
```

My Kafka topic is having 10 partitions. Here I am calling kafkaProducer.send() 20 times and hence 20 Kafka call. how can I send whole data in a batch i.e. in one Kafka call, but again I want to ensure each record goes to specific partition driven by formula **key%10** as in

*ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord(topic,
                        **key%10**, input.get(key));*

Options I see: **linger.ms=1** may ensure that but with a latency of 1ms. 
How to avoid this latency and to avoid 20 network(Kafka) call or to minimize Kafka calls?

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka Producer API already sends messages in batches even though you call individually one by one

See `batch.size` in the docs, it is by bytes, not messages, but you can force an actual network event by calling flush on the Producer

Regarding the Partitions, you'll need to create your code Partitioner. Simply passing the mod value as a key doesn't guarantee you won't have a hash collision in the default partitioner

Comment: Thanks for clarifications!